# Yii 2 block a url if not logged in

Tags: php, url, yii, yii2

This is a bit different to what you may think from the title.

Essentially i have a script that creates a downloadable CSV export. I need to block the url to this file if you are not logged in to the site.

However this script has no controller / model / view associated with it.

The location is:

```
{My site route directory}/web/export/index.php
```

If this was an action in a controller i could achieve this easily but i'm unsure how to do this/or if its even possible in yii2.

If this was in laravel i could go into the routes file and block access, so is there an equivalent in yii2 to laravel routes file maybe?

And before you ask if i can recreate in an action etc... i can not.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (Yii:isGuest()) {
     //redirect
     //or exception
}
```

Comment: where does this go? , as i have no controller action related to the file?

Comment: Why you have't a controller action? Create action  and control user state, if user is't a guest -> start CSV export from your method.